# How to make a discord bot to auto send messages?

Tags: discord, bots

Is it possible to make a bot to automatically message people in my friends list or everyone from a specific server where i'm not an administrator? Where would i start, i know some Python but never worked with Discord bots, i was thinking this shouldn't be too hard as a first one?

I know i've received various messages / adveritsements from people on discord that i wouldn't think are admin on any server i'm on. Unless its done manually?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're talking about is a self bot, which is against the Discord TOS and will likely get your account banned. If you want to get a bot on a Discord Server you'll have to ask an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to write your own Discord bot in python, have a look at [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py), follow the tutorial which will show you how to write simple commands and automated responses.

> Is it possible to make a bot to automatically message people in my friends list or everyone from a specific server where i'm not an administrator?

You must have the required permissions to add the bot to the discord server. A role with 'regular' permissions will typically not allow you to do this. Additionally you can only have discord bots bound to a **server**, so a 'personal' bot that follows you around different servers is not really feasible.

Comment: Is it possible to make a bot that can run commands of other bots?